# DataGridView add row shows scrambled row on bottom

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am building a simple tool to edit a semicolon seperated value files and I use a datagridview to show and edit the data. When I show the data in the datagridview, the text in the last row is shown badly which is weird, because the last row should be empty. This happens when I have `AllowUserToAddRows` on true. When I put this property to false, the last row is shown correctly but I want to be able to add rows to the datagridview. I tried to do this with a work around by adding an empty row via clicking a button and then execute the following line of code: `DataTable.Rows.Add();` where DataTable is of type DataGridView but then the same rendering issue happens again. And in both cases, when I click the wrongly rendered row and I click a different row, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on `rowIndex`. Is this a bug in the DataGridView and if so, is there a work around for it, where I can load a text-based, semicolon seperated value file in a DataGridView and being able to add lines to it? Or do I have to changes some properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the file to `DataTable` correctly.
Then set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` to the data table which you load using the file. Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to true an then save the `DataTable` back to the file.

**Example**

Let's say here is the file content:

```
Column1;Column2
a1;b1
a2;b2
a3;b3
```

And we expect to show them in a `DataGridView` like following:

```
| Column1     | Column2    |
|=============|============|
|a1           |b1          |
|-------------|------------|
|a2           |b2          |
|-------------|------------|
|a3           |b3          |
|-------------|------------|
|             |            |
|-------------|------------|
```

You can simply load and save data using the following code:

```
DataTable dt;
string fileName = @"d:\file1.txt";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = LoadFile(fileName);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFile(dt, fileName);
}
```

*LoadFile*

```
DataTable LoadFile(string fileName)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    if (lines.Count() == 0)
        return dt;
    lines.First().Split(';').ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(x));
    });
    lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(x.Split(';'));
    });
    return dt;
}
```

*SaveFile*

```
public void SaveFile(DataTable dt, string fileName)
{
    var list = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
    list.Add(dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName));
    list.AddRange(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.ItemArray.Cast<string>()));
    var lines = list.Select(x => string.Join(";", x));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using a DataTable as datasource works. I was try to reach my goal without using the datasource but I guess that won't work.